# Realm Object Server

Tags: xamarin, realm, ros, realm-object-server, realm-browser

I am developing Xamarin app(ios, android) using ros(realm object server).
1. how to connect ros with ros studio and realm browser.

i entered my ip address, host info:

[image]

it is result. i dont know what is form:

[image: image]]

i want use url only.
2. i want to know how to set realm object server URL. now i always have localhost:9080. i cant find infomation about that anywhere.

3. Can i connect ros in mac with realmstudio in windows?
   plz..

Comment: What versions of Realm are you using...?

Comment: realm-core-2.8.6, realm-sysnc-1.10.5

Comment: Did my answer below help you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL entered when connecting to the Realm Object Server should use the http:// or https:// protocol and you should make sure that it also has the right port.

In your case I would expect that you can connect

```
http://192.168.0.190:9080
```

.. if you're running ROS on your local developer machine you can simply use

```
http://localhost:9080
```

also, you should the username + password should match that of the ROS server. This is realm-admin and an empty password, if you havn't changed it.

Comment: late response! im sorry. i had a decision that my project dont use realm. thank you!